# check for min value if no numbers check for string Excel

Tags: string, excel, int

I am doing an excel spreadsheet and I need to do min and max cloumnsbut on some occasions I need to check if it says Complies I.E a row may have just text strings or could have numbers or could have both but I need one formula to solve all my problems.

First I need to check for min value then if there are no numbers check for the word "Complies" and then check for "Will Comply".

Comment: Can you edit your post? If so, then try to add an example of your excel sheet.

Comment: I cant post up the sheet for legal reason as it is a confidential work document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
=IF(COUNT(A:A)<>0,MIN(A:A),IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"Complies")>0,"Complies",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"Will Comply")>0,"Will Comply","XX")))
```

1. if column **A** has numbers, you see the minimum value
2. if column **A** has no numbers, but has "Complies", you see "Complies"
3. if column **A** has no numbers and has no "Complies", but has "Will Comply", you see "Will Comply"
4. if column **A** has none of the above, you see "XX"

Answer (score 0):

After A bit of altering I came up with this. It's messy but I think it works.
 =IF(MIN(B16:F16),MIN(B16:F16),IF(OR(B16=0,C16=0,D16=0,E16=0,F16=0),0,IF(OR(B16="Complies",C16="Complies",D16="Complies",E16="Complies",F16="Complies"),"Complies",(IF(OR(B16="Will Comply",C16="Will Comply",D16="Will Comply",E16="Will Comply",F16="Will Comply"),"Will Comply","")))))